# UITableView has no member 'dequeueReusableCell'

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I'm attempting to make a list using a UITableView and am getting the error:

[UITableView] has no member 'dequeueReusableCell'

I have created a table ui with a prototype cell that has the identifier "CellController".

I have initialised my table view at the beginning of my class

```
@IBOutlet var myTaskListView: [UITableView]!
```

Then when I'm trying to declare a new cell I'm unable to use dequeueReusableCell

```
let cell = myTaskListView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(CellController)) as! CellController
```

Is there something more I have to do to make "dequeueReusableCell" a member of UITableView?

I'm relatively new to Xcode and swift programming, I hope I provided everything needed to help solve the issue.

Comment: `myTaskListView` is an array of `UITableView`, no? That's where is your issue.

Comment: *A list using a UITableView* is usually **multiple** cells in **one** table view.

Comment: the `UITableView` __has__ such method, but `[UITableView]` has not.

Comment: Thank you! I suppose I was confused on what a "collection" meant. I was thinking of it in terms of a collection of cells, not a collection of tables.

Answer (score 4):

There is problem with outlet that you have created for your table view.

```
@IBOutlet var myTaskListView: [UITableView]!
```

You can try this:

```
@IBOutlet var yourTableView: UITableView!

let cell : yourCell = self.yourTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "yourCellIdentifier") as! yourCell
```